# Download file from another directory AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-handling

I'm working on an angularJS project and I have to trigger a download of a .txt file when the user clicks the download button.
But the file is present in another directory

```html
 <a ng-if="ErrorReport && ErrorMessage" href="../../C:\Users\Ali\Pictures\{{ErrorReport}}.txt"
           class="btn btn-primary"
           download>
            Download error report
        </a>
```

The text file (to be downloaded) is an error report which is created by the API on run-time so it would always have a dynamic name that's why I have used{{ErrorReport}} in the href

Any idea how I could give it the reference to a text file outside the app's directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-href` instead of href in your html along with giving the absolute path what browser understands. `ng-href` will help to bind the scope content.

```html
 <a ng-if="ErrorReport && ErrorMessage" ng-href="file:///C:/Users/Ali/Pictures/{{ErrorReport}}.txt"
           class="btn btn-primary"
           download>
            Download error report
        </a>
```

But it wont solve your issue completely. You are trying to access a local resource from your browser. For this you need to allow your browser to access your local files.

Go to Chrome executable and then run below cmd

```
.\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Now you can access files from your local but again its **Dangerous**.

It will leave your file system open for access from browser. Documents originating from anywhere have any access to local `file:///` resources.

Better you run an instance of server in the folder your file is present and access that file like `http://localhost:8080/file.txt`.

You can use chrome extension **200 OK** for that or you can `install` http-server globally using node's package manager like

```
npm install -g http-server
```

and from your command prompt you can start server like

```
C:\Users\Ali\Pictures> http-server
```

Hope this will solve your problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
href="file:///C:\Users\Ali\Pictures\{{ErrorReport}}.txt"
```

Your were using a relative path syntax with an absolute one,

so my example is using the correct absolute path